# virtuemart2 and sh404sef url

Tags: url, joomla2.5, virtuemart

I'm using virtuemart 2.5.6 and sh404sef 4.4.4.1791 in joomla2.5
My problem is that, sh404sef url generates child category name and category/product id along with the sef url.

forexmaple,

i need
http://domain.com/childcategoryname.html
but it displays as
http://domain.com/view/category/virtuemart_category_id/196/start/0.html

for main category it displays correctly but for child category and products, url is displaying as mentioned above.

I have tried altering the settings.
in vm2 configuration, SEF has been disabled, using product id is unchecked
in sh404sef configuration, disabled allowing id in url

How to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Check your menu if these subcategories exist and disable them to check if the issue is getting fixed.

If not you have to check and modify sh404sef plugin at: /components/com_sh404sef/sef_ext/com_virtuemart.php

If nothing of the above works, you could disable sh404sef plugin and use virtuemart rooter by setting sh404sef configuration -> by component -> com_virtuemart -> use joomla rooter.

In order to work you have to enable:

> System -> Global configuration -> Search Engine Friendly URLs
>
> System -> Global configuration -> Use URL rewriting

Comment: I have enabled SEF url in globalk configuration. but it doesn't work. I think problem arises with virtuemart configuration seo.

Comment: do you have disabled sef plugin from sef404 configuration?
sh404sef configuration -> by component -> com_virtuemart -> use joomla rooter

Comment: yes tried by using default setting and with joomla rooter

Comment: Seem that something is wrong with your sef404 configuration. Please try to disable sef404 to see if the problem is getting fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I have cleared this issue by disable Sef in vm configuration, child category and products are displaying correctly.

But vmError('$link["view"] is empty'); errors occurs

By referring to this link 
http://forum.virtuemart.net/index.php?topic=98211.0

problem has been temporarily gets cleared.